# a continuous map from a closed interval to a closed interval

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Suppose $f$ is a continuous map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0 $ and $f(1)=1$,can we conclude that $f$ is a surjective map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $f[[0,1]]$ is connected and the only connected subset of $[0,1]$ that contains $0$ and $1$ is $[0,1]$: if $0 < p < 1$ is not in $f[[0,1]]$, then $f^{-1}[[0,p)]$ and $f^{-1}[(p,1]]$ would disconnect $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this follows by intermediate value property.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem